# Prevent a series of section headings overrunning the length of a page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

I'm in the process of writing a requirements document and have been using a simple template. The problem I'm running into is that when I compile my document, in certain places, the text over-runs the page. A MWE of the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Specific Requirements}
\section{External Interface Requirements}

\subsubsection{foo}

\section{Functional Requirements}

\subsection{Sign In}

\subsection{Profile Page}

\subsubsection{foo}
\subsubsection{foo}
\subsubsection{foo}
\subsubsection{foo}
\subsubsection{foo}
\subsubsection{foo}
\subsubsection{foo}
\subsubsection{foo}
\subsubsection{foo}
\subsubsection{foo}

\subsubsection{some of these subsections will run off the page}
\subsubsection{some of these subsections will run off the page}
\subsubsection{some of these subsections will run off the page}
\subsubsection{some of these subsections will run off the page}
\subsubsection{some of these subsections will run off the page}
\subsubsection{some of these subsections will run off the page}
\subsubsection{some of these subsections will run off the page}
\subsubsection{some of these subsections will run off the page}
\subsubsection{some of these subsections will run off the page}
\subsubsection{some of these subsections will run off the page}
\subsubsection{some of these subsections will run off the page}
\subsubsection{some of these subsections will run off the page}

\end{document}
```

If you compile it, you should see some of the subsections marked "some of these ..." running off the bottom of the page, and indeed, covering the page number.

Comment: You need to add some text between the levels. THis is the normal way. Such headings using `\nobreak` to avoid the splitting from the section title to the text.

Comment: That's very helpful and actually provided me a way to solve my problem. I had originally wanted to have numbering of the form 1.2.3.4 requirement using \subsection{requirement}, but if I switch to 1.2.3.4<newline>requirement  using \subsection{}<newline>requirement, I avoid the page overrun problem as well as another page break problem I was having. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems to me you are abusing sectiong commands for what should be a list or something...

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Make that an answe, please (or cast the first vote to close).

Comment: @lockstep: let us close the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is likely not to be of much help for future visitors to this site.

Comment: @Werner how can you presume to know what will be or won't be useful to all future humans who visit this site?

Comment: @s.matthew.english: First of all, future visitors will have to find this post. If they do, then they'll probably have to have the same *fictitious* example file, which is the only way they can replicate this behaviour. It's fictitious because it is highly unlikely that someone will create a document that only contains sequential sectional units (bricks) would any text (mortar) between them. Even if they do, by chance, land here and want a solution, this solution is given in the first comment. If you feel this question should be re-opened, flag it for moderator attention and justify it.

Comment: @s.matthew.english I can see why it was closed but probably it can be generalised to make it useful

Comment: @Werner I'm going to edit and reopen here: it's not unknown for people to do a 'set up' phase with a document just using the section headings ...

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX does not allow page breaks immediately after section headings. As such, setting up an 'outline' just containing headings will lead to a long run of text that has no valid place to break, and so you'll see an over-running effect. As with graphics that are too big, what you get here is a blank page as LaTeX first tries to fit the material on the first one, can't, leaves it for the next (full) page and then simply dumps what it has.

You have a couple of options. The first is not to worry: assuming this is a 'sketch' outline for your own memory, you can simply wait until the document is fleshed out. If you need to be able to give the output to someone else, a forced break (`\break`) or indeed some filler text ('This is filler.') placed correctly will do the job.

If you are never intending to put any text after the headings than they are not `\section`s but rather some form of list structure. Those *can* break across pages: what you'll need to do is adjust formatting as required.